# Connecting to BAM internal cassandra

Tags: cassandra, wso2

Now I am trying BAM 2.3.0 and I want to know the way to connect to BAM internal Cassandra from different server. Is it possible or it is tightly coupled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not tightly coupled. Similar to making standalone Cassandra cluster you must do the configuration but since you not creating a cluster but to access from external server no need to give seed addesses. Just configure the listen and rpc address. The location of the cassandra.yaml is `BAM_HOME/repository/conf/etc`.

In the cassandra.yaml change `listen_address` and `rpc_address` to your IP address. If you put `127.0.0.1` the Cassandra will only listen to the connections coming from the localhost, therefore you cannot access from outside.